How can I extract a custom claim named "client_id" using jwt-authorizer Rust crate on Axum?
This is the crate I'm using on Cargo.toml of my axum project:
jwt-authorizer = "0.14.0"

This is the main method:
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let auth: Authorizer =
        JwtAuthorizer::from_jwks_url(env!("SSO_AUTH_REALM")).build().await.unwrap();

    let routes_balances = saldos::saldos_routes::routes();
    let routes_all = Router::new()
        .merge(routes_balances)
        .layer(middleware::from_fn(audit_middleware))
        .layer(middleware::map_response(main_response_mapper))
        .layer(auth.into_layer())
        .fallback_service(routes_static());


    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:8080").await.unwrap();
    println!("->> LISTENING on {:?}\n", listener.local_addr());
    axum::serve(listener, routes_all.into_make_service())
        .await
        .unwrap();
    Ok(())

This is my method signature:
#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize, Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Claims {
    pub client_id: String,
}

#[debug_handler]
pub async fn find_saldo(
    Path(conta_string): Path<String>,
    query_params: Query<QueryParams>,
    header_map: HeaderMap,
    JwtClaims(user_token): JwtClaims<Claims>,
    State(client): State<Client>,
) -> Result<Json<SaldoDTO>, Error> {


    println!("#### USER FROM TOKEN {:?}", user_token.client_id);

I would like access the client_id custom claim.
This claim can't be retrieved from the JwtClaims(user): JwtClaims<RegisteredClaims>
How can I get it?

You just need to create your own type that derives serde::Deserialize and Clone.  You can have RegisteredClaims do most of the heavy lifting using #[serde(flatten)].
#[derive(Clone, serde::Deserialize)]
struct Claims {
    #[serde(flatten)]
    pub standard: RegisteredClaims,
    pub client_id: ClientId,
}

Since you did not specify what the type of the client_id field is, I've used the placeholder ClientId here.  Substitute it for the actual type of the field.
Then, you'll be able to use JwtClaims<Claims>.

cdhowie, unfortunately it does not work, returning 401, although the token really has this claim.
I complemented the answer with more parts of the code.

@swerts Try writing a test method where you decode the hardcoded token yourself and see what error the JWT decode function gives you.
